# @Html.Raw not outputting anything

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

```
    <script>
    @if (ViewBag.EnableJump != null && ViewBag.EnableJump == true)
    {
        ViewBag.EnableJump = false;
       
        @Html.Raw("alert('it worked')");
    }
    </script>
```

EnableJump is not null and is set to true. I also know for a fact that its getting inside the if because I can deliberately throw an exception from in there. However, I cannot output additional javascript using Html.Raw or  even though every stupid google result I have seen so far says I am doing it correctly. What do I have to do to make Html.Raw work?

Comment: Code works fine...   Tested it and I get the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code inside a `<text></text>` pseudo element.

[This article](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax) describes the various ways to get multiple lines of content inside your Razor page.

Comment: Putting it in the `<text>` is not needed. Only when you want actual text in a razor block: `@if (ViewBag.EnableJump != null) { <text>Normal Text</text> }`